# User defined type from stored procedure not detected in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, table-valued-parameters

I have created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[zsp_MoveItemsToFolder]
    (@IdListToMove IdListToMove READONLY,
     @FolderId INT,
     @UserId INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Rowcount INT = 1;

    WHILE (@Rowcount > 0)   
        UPDATE TOP (5000) dbo.SingleScannedItems   --<-- define Batch Size in TOP Clause
        SET MyListId = @FolderId
        WHERE SingleScannedItemId IN (SELECT l.SingleScannedItemIds 
                                      FROM @IdListToMove l) 
          AND UserId = @UserId

        SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
        CHECKPOINT;   --<-- to commit the changes with each batch
END
```

Prior to that I have created a user defined type in SQL like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdListToMove] AS TABLE(
    [SingleScannedItemIds] int NULL
);
```

And once I have imported the procedure into the C# LINQ the only parameters that I can see are FolderId and UserId.

However the `@IdListToMove` user defined type is not visible in the imported stored procedure :/...

So my question is: why is the user defined type not visible in the imported stored procedure (that is imported through the Entity Framework 6)

How do I fix this so that I can pass the list through C# into the stored procedure?

Can someone help me out?

Edit: here's the modified procedure with @Marc Gravel's suggestions:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[zsp_MoveItemsToFolder]
    (@IdListToMove NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @FolderId INT,
     @UserId INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Rowcount INT = 1;

    WHILE (@Rowcount > 0)   
        UPDATE TOP (5000) dbo.SingleScannedItems   --<-- define Batch Size in TOP Clause
        SET MyListId = @FolderId
        WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM dbo.SplitStringProduction(@IdListToMove,',') S1 
                       WHERE SingleScannedItemId = S1.val)) 
          AND UserId = @UserId 
          AND MyListId <> @FolderId

        SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
        CHECKPOINT;   --<-- to commit the changes with each batch
END
```

Comment: LINQ isn't an ORM. It's a query language that runs on top of collections like List<T> or ORMs like NHibernate or EF. `imported the procedure into the C# LINQ` has no meaning. *Which* ORM are you using? Which version? How did you "import" the stored procedure?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was using Entity framework 6 and ADO.NET to import the procedure

Comment: minor observation: that `update` looks like it could keep changing the same 5000 forever... you might want an additional predicate of `AND MyListId <> @FolderId`? although frankly, I'd probably just run it as one batch... and I'd probably use `string_split` instead of a custom type

Comment: @MarcGravell yes good point I was going to do that with split string. For the batches updating, sometimes the passed list can contain perhaps up to 50000-100000 items to update, so maybe I should somehow modify the batch logic to work faster ? ^_^

Comment: @MarcGravell How could I modify so it doesn't go work forever and in batches of 2500 items lets say? Could you show me?

Comment: you'd add `AND MyListId <> @FolderId` - that way, things you've already updated are automatically excluded (note: I'm assuming that neither `MyListId` nor `@FolderId` are `null` here)

Comment: @MarcGravell ah  so basically leave everything as is just add that statement ? ^_^ Okay one sec I will post the updated procedure'

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm posting updated procedure with split string method and the suggestion you posted. Could  you look into it if its okay?

Comment: @MarcGravell I posted an updated procedure ^^

Comment: It would probably run faster if you `join dbo.SplitStringProduction(@IdListToMove, ',') s1 on s1.Val=cast(SingleScannedItemId as nvarchar(10))`. The way it's written currently it's likely executing SplitStringProduction() once for every row in SingleScannedItems.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning  WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM join dbo.SplitStringProduction(@IdListToMove, ',') s1 on s1.Val=cast(SingleScannedItemId as nvarchar(10)))  like this ?